# Package does not exist on build but importing without errors?

Tags: java, android-studio, gradle, build

My project was building fine until I added `Kryo` dependency to my project. I can use both `Netty` and `Kryo` without syntax errors in my IDE but it won't build. All I did was adding `Kryo` to my `common` module and started implementing `Kryo` in my code, when I wanted to run `Gradle` it returned a big list of errors about none existent `Netty` and `Kryo` packages.

My gradle is very simple, client and server module both depend on common which atm has 2 custom classes and implement `Kryo` and `Netty`.

```
project(":common") {
    apply plugin:'java'
    dependencies {
        // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.netty/netty-all
        implementation group: 'io.netty', name: 'netty-all', version: '4.1.33.Final'
        // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.esotericsoftware.kryo/kryo
        implementation group: 'com.esotericsoftware.kryo', name: 'kryo', version: '2.24.0'
    }
}

project(":server") {
    apply plugin:'java'
    dependencies {
        implementation project(":common")
        // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mongodb.morphia/morphia
        compile group: 'org.mongodb.morphia', name: 'morphia', version: '1.3.2'
    }
}

project(":client") {
    apply plugin:'java'
    dependencies {
        implementation project(":common")
    }
}
```

In client and server (both just java applications atm) I am using `Kryo` and `Netty` without syntax errors but when I run or build I get the following list for each class that imports `Netty` or `Kryo`.

```
error: package io.netty.channel does not exist  
error: package io.netty.channel does not exist  
error: package io.netty.channel does not exist  
error: package io.netty.channel.group does not exist    
error: cannot find symbol class ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter    
error: cannot find symbol class ChannelGroup    
error: cannot find symbol class ChannelHandlerContext   
error: cannot find symbol class ChannelGroup    
error: cannot find symbol class ChannelHandlerContext   
error: cannot find symbol class ChannelHandlerContext   
error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype  
error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
```

I tried the most obvious `invalidate cache / restart`, cleaning, rebuilding without success. Apart from that I tried fiddling with the plugin, setting it to `java-library` and back. The only thing I did differently then usual is that I tried to exclude `Kryo` for the other 2 modules but I gave up on that after a few attempts for the time being and erased those `exclude` lines. It's probably just something I overlooked but I can't put my finger on it.

Comment: Mmmh so you're on IDEA. Backup .idea/modules.xml, delete it, everything will probably disappear, reimport from the Gradle Tool Window.

Comment: @LppEdd that did not work. Since this takes way too long and still is a rather small project, I think the fastest way to fix this is to create a new project and copy/paste my code into it.

Comment: yeah! But I don't understand one thing, why are you populating dependencies in a single Gradle file? Why don't use each module build.gradle to add them?

Comment: @LppEdd All projects that need the common library depend on them hence I add them to common. This used to work flawlessly.

Comment: I'd say the most correct approach would be to delegate dependencies to each module, for separation of concerns. Then, on the common one, simply require them as "implementation".